# UV unwraping help in blender

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I've been having trouble figuring out how to uv unwrap my main character model in a game I'm creating. I've done quite a bit of research and can't seem to figure out how to do it. Basically when I try to unwrap nothing happens in the UV/Image editor which just shows these box things, It was previously just completely black until I pressed reset in the uv menu. I'm trying to unwrap it so that I can texture it in blender using the painting thing. I'd appreciate any help here's a screenshot that hopefully shows you whats going on:
[image: Thingy]

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried using 'Smart Unwrap' and have you tried turning off 'use nodes' in the material? If you get the unwrap to show, then make sure you have an image loaded there to paint to and see if that helps.

Comment: I suggest to change the title of your question. As it is now I have the impression you want to change the UV while running the game. Your description mentions that you are struggling with Blender (While editing the assets).

Comment: Hey Craig that worked thanks a ton, for some reason just using the smart UV project option and leaving the settings as is worked. I changed the title monster.